# Default Query to Report and pick datas

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to set a default query to do a report in Laravel 5.1. After that I set this default query, I'm 
trying put some conditions with were and get these results in variables.

For example:

```
$tasks = Task::whereBetween('created_at', [$date1, $date2]);

$closed = $tasks->where('closed', 1)->count();

$re_open = $tasks->where('reopen', 1)->count();
```

The problem is:

When I returned the $closed the number is alright, but when I returned the $re_open the count is 0, because the query adds the second condition for re-open with the first condition for closed.

Like this:

```
select * from `tasks` where `created_at` between ? and ? and `closed` = ? and `reopen` = ?
```

The query in $tasks is always the same for all the report. How can i get the second condition using the default query without copy the query in all my code?

Thanks!!!

Comment: is there only closed and re_open tasks records ? if yes why you don't get re_open from $task->count() - $closed

Comment: No. This is only a example, in the report i have several columns and I intend put several conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best answer, but I solved the problem with this:

I set the default query:

```
$query = Task::whereBetween('created_at', [$date1, $date2]);
```

and use this for each filter:

```
$tasks  = clone $query;
$closed = $tasks->where('closed', 1)->get();

$tasks  = clone $query;
$reopen = $tasks->where('reopen', 1)->get();
```

Ok, I have 2 lines for 1 query, but if my default query has more filters with this way is more clean.

Thanks